# Select text column from table in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having difficulty figuring this out. I have an incident table that contains columns `id`, `comments`, `incidentdate`, and `incidentdescID`. There are 10 years worth of data in this table. I wrote a stored procedure to extract the last 4 years worth of data but I am running into the following error.

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 27
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

So when I change the date range for the incident to be between 2015 to 2016 I am not getting an error. Then when I change it to be between 2017-2018 I am still not getting an  error. But when I change it to be between 2016-2017 I get the error. Also when I comment out the `comments` column, I do not get an error no matter what date range I put.

So I was thinking there might be a special character in the `Comments` column which is a `text` column in the `Incident` table. If that is the case how would I be able to select that column but remove the special characters in the stored procedure without making changes to the table?

Comment: We need more information about what the stored procedure does please.  When you say it "extracts" data, is it inserting it to another table?  The `String or binary data would be truncated` error is usually because you are inserting into a column that is not defined with enough space.  This can occur if you select into a temp table without defining the schema first and SQL samples the data and happens to pick the wrong size.

Comment: Hi Scott thank you for commenting. I will post my code in a couple min. I am writing a comma delimited stores procedure. It is inserting it into a results table. The comments column is being inserted into a column in the results table that is varchar(500). Which is more than enough space.

Comment: You can test your theory by changing the varchar(500) to a varchar(max).   If the error doesn't occur, then you DO have a comment more than 500 characters, and 500 isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect your "Comments" column is the culprit then you can search my friend for junk values. I got this error once and fixed by replacing char(10) and char(13) by blanks.

1.

```
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(tbl.comments, CHAR(10), '*JUNK*'), CHAR(13), '*JUNK*') AS CleandComments 
    FROM [your table name] tbl
```

2. Copy your query result into any editor and search for records corresponding *JUNK* keywords.

This ideally happens when you are importing data from excels or source tables with `NVARCHAR` datatype whereas your destination is a CSV or accepts only `VARCHAR`.

If above is your case then you simply need to put `REPLACE` function on your column/s in your procedure